# how do I remove copper stain coming from plumbing?

Tags: cleaning, removal, stain, copper, copper-tubing

I have that blue stain in my bathtub

[image]

The stain comes from my plumbing, which probably contains copper that rusted 
and creates that stain.

I tried to remove it with bleacher but to no avail.

Do you have any ideas on how I can remove copper stains like this one, please?

Thanks

Comment: You can try vinegar.

Comment: hi @ajeh, the test was successful. Please write your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: But the next question is, why are you getting copper stains? I would be worried that something is wrong with water or piping.

Comment: @ajeh long story short. My boiler was having massive issues causing over heated water, changed it, change the fausset that was oxydating and now, everything is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vinegar should be able to dissolve copper stains. Those stains are commonly copper hydroxocarbonate AKA copper carbonate hydroxide, which easily dissolves into copper acetate.

Answer (score 3):

There are products sold for your specific issue. Check your local hardware store or home improvement center for CLR (Calcium-Lime-Rust) cleaner. CLR is a specific brand name but there are many formulations of similar products available.